# mb_convert_variables(): Cannot handle recursive references

Tags: php, linux-mint, php.ini

Здравствуйте, система Mint 17.3 получил автоматические обновления для php5.6. Система предложила оставить старый php.ini или заменить на новый. Выбрал "загрузить новую оболочку чтобы..." дословно не помню. Все сразу зависло.

Перезапустил затем `sudo dpkg --configure -a` и оставил текущий php.ini после чего начал получать следующую ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 
'mb_convert_variables(): Cannot handle recursive references' in /var/www...
```

Как бы починить и из-за чего такое, не нагуглил ни чего.(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка пришла Вам вместе с обновлением:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73322
Ее исправление в процессе, так что два варианта: ждать обновлений или откатиться назад.

Comment: Благодарю, видел эту ссылку но только сейчас осмыслил)